# C++ Program: Finding even digits

Tags: c++

I need some help on my code.
The program has to find an even digits (if there's atleast one) and get the count of 'em.
Example:
User Inputs - 11555249, Program outputs - "The repeated digits are 1 (2x times) and 5 (3x times) ".

My program works as far as I input for instance 114, then it shows Digit 1 repeats x2 times, but if I put 11455, it won't output 5's (they're repeating as well), it will only output the smallest digit that repeats.
I'll highly appreciate any suggestions.

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int stop;

do{
    int n;
    int *myArray;
    int count = 1;


    cout << "Input number: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    double x = n;
    x = x / 10;

    // Finds the amount of digits in number[inputted]
    while(x > 1)
    {
        x = x/10;
        count++;
    }
    myArray = new int [count];

    // Puts every digit into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = n%10;
        n = n / 10;
    }



    int countEvenDigits = 0; // If there are even digits in the number, it will count them.

    // Checking if there are any even digits
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        for (int h = j + 1; h < count; h++)
        {
            if (myArray[j] == myArray[h])
            {
                 ++countEvenDigits;
                 cout << "Digit that repeats is: " << myArray[j] << " and their amount is: " << countEvenDigits << endl;
            }


        }








    cout << "To continue this program, press - (1); otherwise - (0)" << endl;
    cin >> stop;

    delete[] myArray;
}while (stop == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's an "*even* digit"? Your example is very *odd*.

Comment: @Maartin1996 Is 1 a repeated digit in  number 121?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes! :)

Comment: @Maartin1996 Do you still need a solution?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm still trying to figure it out, yes. I updated code lil bit, but I still struggle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you are calling 'even'.  You are assigning 'even' to the first digit in your array:

```
int even = myArray[0];
```

Then you are counting it in some loop:

```
int countEvenDigits = 1; // If there are even digits in the number, it will count them.

// Checking if there are any even digits
for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
{

    if (myArray[j] == even)
        {
        countEvenDigits++;
        even = myArray[j];


        }


}
```

But you never in fact go to the next element of your array (eg. myArray[1], myArray[2].  You need to iterate through all of those and store each 'countEvenDigits in a separate array (not a single one).  Then when you print it out,

```
cout << "Digit that repeats is: " << even << " and their amount is: " << countEvenDigits << endl;
```

You probably have to go through some loop of your array, and print out:

```
for loop..
  if (countEvenDigits[i] > 1){
    cout << myArray[i] << " repeats " << countEvenDigits[i] << " times ";
  }
```

Comment: Also `myArray` contains numbers in reverse order after the execution of this loop: for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = n%10;
            n = n / 10;

        }   and there is no need for `x = x / 10;` before the while loop.

Comment: doesn't matter.. as long as countEvenDigits[] and myArray[] are in the same order, then change the for loop to go end to beginning to print out properly.

Comment: you'd have to update the question above, code in comments is illegible.